# How to call .NET method of DocuWare API with Nullable arguments from Java

Tags: java, c#

When I try to invoke the .NET method – ‘Create’ from Java using Javonet I get a message the method does not exist because I am not passing the correct parameters –

```
DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection 
Create(System.Uri, 
                   System.String, 
                   System.String, 
                   System.String, 
                   System.Nullable`1[DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.DWProductTypes], 
                   System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, 
                   System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue[]
                   )
```

My code is –

```
NObject objUri = Javonet.New("Uri","http://<IP-address>/DocuWare/Platform");

NType serviceConnectionClass = Javonet.getType("DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection");  

NObject objProductInfoHeaderValue = Javonet.New("System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue","DocuWare+.NET+API+Test+Client", "1.0"); 
NObject[] objProductInfoHeaderValueArray = new NObject[] {objProductInfoHeaderValue};  

NType typeHttpMessageHandler = Javonet.getType("System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler");

NType typeNullable = Javonet.getType("System.Nullable");

serviceConnectionClass.invoke("Create",objUri,"admin","admin","<company-name>",typeNullable,typeHttpMessageHandler,objProductInfoHeaderValueArray);
```

My main problem is not knowing how to generate ‘Nullable’ objects for –

```
DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.DWProductTypes
System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler
System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue[]
```

I don't think this is a problem with JavONet, but I need to get past this problem before I can perform a Proof-of-concept

Here is the link to the Docuware Platform –

http://help.docuware.com/sdk/platform-eagle/html/66b2ed1e-2aef-452a-97cd-5014bbf0242b.htm

I am running the Test using Tomcat app server and JSP.  I know the .NET .dll are being found and the Javonet library is being correctly activated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for nullable arguments you can pass either the regular target type in your case some enum value of "**DWProductTypes**" or if you want to pass null just pass the "null";

**So you should make the call:**

```
serviceConnectionClass.invoke("Create",objUri,"admin", "admin","Intermodal Tank",new NEnum("DWProductTypes","DocuWareClient"),typeHttpMessageHandler,objProductInfoHeaderValueArray);
```

All possible values for DWProductTypes you can find here: 
http://help.docuware.com/sdk/platform/html/T_DocuWare_Platform_ServerClient_DWProductTypes.htm

Here you find more about using enumerations:
https://www.javonet.com/quick-start-guide/#Enums_How_To_Work_With_Enums

**or pass null:**

```
serviceConnectionClass.invoke("Create",objUri,"admin", "admin","Intermodal Tank",null,typeHttpMessageHandler,objProductInfoHeaderValueArray);

For argument HttpMessageHandler just create the instance:
NObject typeHttpMessageHandler = Javonet.New("SomeConcreteTypeInheritingFromHttpMessageHandler");
```

For **ProductInfoHeaderValue** array you should create Java array of **NObjects** and pass it as argument:

```
NObject[] objProductInfoHeaderValueArray = new NObject[1];
objProductInfoHeaderValueArray[0] = Javonet.New("ProductInfoHeaderValue","productName","version");
```